# How can I dual install Ubuntu 10.4 in a Mac Mini with 10.4.11?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, mac-mini, osx-tiger, refit

I'd like to power-up my aging Mac Mini (1.5GHz Core Solo, 1GB RAM, Tiger 10.4.11) by installing a shiny Ubuntu alongside the current OS. After all, I use Ubuntu for everything save for cleaning my teeth.

Since it's my first and only Mac and I have next to no experience with the OS (having used it basically as a media player) I am a little concerned about rEFIt, ELILO, Boot Camp and the fact that it's basically a 4.5 years old unsupported machine and I might get asleep reinstalling everything several times.

I've used the live desktop-i386 CD and everything works. I tried with an external USB drive instead of a CD but couldn't make it boot.

As for installing Ubuntu, the howtos I've found give several alternatives depending on the model, the OSX version, etc.. but they usually talk about newer machines.

Which howto should I follow to repartition, and boot thereafter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using parallels? (or some other VMWare). The advantage to this for me is that I can nuke an installed OS and reinstall it without having to go through a ton of trouble. In addition, you can install multiple OSes using the VM model. So if you wanted to run two versions of Ubuntu for example it will allow it.

The beauty of this is the main OS never has to get scrubbed AND you can leave your media player in tact while you are working with the other OSes.

Comment: No, because it's an old Mini, 1GB RAM and slow.